# Detect Success Page on Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Is there a way to check if am I on Success page on Magento 2?

I know in Magento 1 we can check and compare the action name, for example. But in Magento 2, there is something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be via URL.

In your Class use this in construct:

```
public function __construct(
        // ...
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,    
        // ...
    )
    {        
        //...
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        // ...
    }
```

With `$this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl()` you get the current url, so you can check against your checkout success url.